# testcafe running different tests based on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, testcafe

I was wondering if there is a way to somehow pass a parameter to let your fixture or even all tests know which browser they are running in.

In my particular case, I would use that parameter to simply assign a corresponding value to a variable inside my tests.

For example,

```
    switch(browser) {
            case 'chrome':
                chrome = 'chrome.com';
                break;
            case 'firefox':
                link = 'firefox.com';
                break;
            case 'safari':
                link = 'safari.com';
                break;            
            default:
                break;
}
```

Currently, I was able to achieve something similar by adding a global node variable and it looks something like this:

```
"chrome": "BROWSER=1 node runner.js"
```

However, this makes me create a separate runner for every browser (safari-runner, chrome-runner etc.) and I would like to have everything in one place.

So at the end of the day, I would need to make this work:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        return runner
            .src('test.js')
            .browsers(['all browsers'])
            .run({
                passBrowserId: true // I guess it would look something like this
            });
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to get browser info:

- Get navigator.userAgent from the browser using [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client.html). Optionally you can use a module to parse an user agent string, for example: ua-parser-js.

  ```
  import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
  import uaParser from 'ua-parser-js';

  fixture `get ua`
      .page `https://testcafe.devexpress.com/`;

  const getUA = ClientFunction(() => navigator.userAgent);

  test('get ua', async t => {
      const ua = await getUA();

      console.log(uaParser(ua).browser.name);
  });
  ```
- Use [RequestLogger](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/how-to-access-useragent-or-browser-alias-values-from-within-a-test/516/2) to obtain browser info. For example:

  ```
  import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

  const logger = RequestLogger('https://testcafe.devexpress.com/');

  fixture `test`
      .page('https://testcafe.devexpress.com')
      .requestHooks(logger);

  test('test 1', async t => {
      await t.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok(); 

          const logRecord = logger.requests[0];

          console.log(logRecord.userAgent);
  });
  ```
- The TestCafe team is working on the [t.browserInfo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/481) function, which solves the issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this question, testcafe has now implemented [t.browser](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/browser.html), which will allow you to check the `browser.name` or `browser.alias` to determine which browser you're running in.

```js
import { t } from 'testcafe';

const browserIncludes = b => t.browser.name.includes(b);
const isBrowserStack = () => t.browser.alias.includes('browserstack');

fixture `test`
    .page('https://testcafe.devexpress.com')

test('is Chrome?', async () => {
    console.log(t.browser.name);
    await t.expect(browserIncludes('Chrome').ok();
    await t.expect(isBrowserStack()).notOk();
});
```